# List running Jupyter notebooks and tokens

Tags: python, ssh, jupyter, tmux, gnu-screen

How do you check the login tokens for all running jupyter notebook instances?

Example: you have a notebook running in `tmux` or `screen` permanently, and login in remotely through `ssh`. Sometimes, particularly if you're logging in after a long time, the token is requested again in order to access the notebook session. How do you get hold of the token without having to kill and restart the notebook session with a new token?

Answer (score 180, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You can now just run `jupyter notebook list` in the terminal to get the running jupyter sessions with tokens.

[image]

Take care that you are within the right environment (conda, virtualenv etc.) otherwise the sessions will list without the associated tokens. Eg: The above reference screenshot is from the conda environment.

**Old answer:**

Run ipython and enter the following:

```
> ipython
[1] : system("jupyter" "notebook" "list")
Out[1]: 
['Currently running servers:','http://localhost:8895/token=067470c5ddsadc54153ghfjd817d15b5d5f5341e56b0dsad78a :: /u/user/dir']
```

If the notebook is running on a remote server, you will have to login in to that server first before running ipython.

Comment: Why do it in iPython? The `system` just executes its arguments in a system shell, so you can achieve the same effect just by executing `jupyter notebook list` in the shell.

Comment: You're right, and this is now stated on the jupyter login page

Comment: Note that password authentication and token authentication are mutually exclusive, so if Jupyter is running with a password there won't be any token in the `jupyter notebook list`.

Comment: For **JUPYTER LAB** users: `jupyter notebook list` lists also all running jupyter lab sessions.

Comment: @zwithouta Yes in some cases, but it doesn't seem to work for some reason when running from a poetry-managed virtual environment.

Comment: try `jupyter lab list`

Comment: JupyterLab 3.0 now depends on Jupyter Server, which is a new Jupyter project based on the server portion of the classic Notebook server.

Answer (score 40):

Use this command

```
$ jupyter server list
```

It will display the currently running servers for both `jupyter lab` and `jupyter notebook` along with the tokens.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks. This solved the problem for me.

Comment: This gives me Jupyter command `jupyter-server` not found. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 39):

One easy solution (that can save you time by avoiding opening a new terminal) is **from the same terminal you are running the notebook** to **hit** (ONLY ONCE!! - cause twice would kill the running server)

```
Ctrl + C
```

**By doing that the full link** to your notebook **will appear** (along with the token!) and a prompt asking you to confirm shutting down. Just answer no (`n` and enter) or do nothing and after 5 seconds the operation will resume. In the meanwhile you would have been able to retrieve the link and/or the token you need.

Comment: `jupyter notebook list` doesn't always work for me.  This does.

Comment: While the accepted answer is (imo) the "nice and commendable way", this one is more practical as it gives you exactly the desired token.

Comment: @Him Did you try `jupyter lab list`?

Answer (score 10):

Just right click on the jupyter notebook logo in the currently running server, you probably have a server running already, then click on copy link, then paste the link in a text editor, maybe MS word, you will see the token in the link, copy and paste where token is required. It will work.

Comment: assumes the notebook can be accessed in a browser, which is not always the case when debugging remote sessions

Answer (score -8):

For running python code in jupyter notebook...we need token id which we can obtain from the terminal by just typing ***jupyter notebook*** provided your path has been configured... If not then set your path right first.

[image: Sample]

Comment: this starts a *new* jupyter session, rather than listing the already running sessions with their tokens