# List running jupyter notebook .ipynb files

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipython

I am trying to see which jupyter notebook .ipynb files are still running and trying to shut them down to save memory.
But Google only pointed me to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46551551/3020740) showing how to list jupyter notebook servers which isn't my purpose.

I'm not using Jupyterlab, just Jupyter notebook running on a Linux server with python3

Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: You aren't detailing how you are using Jupyter? There's a lot of possible ways: Is this on a Jupyterhub? Just installed on your computer? [JupyterLab Dekstop application](https://blog.jupyter.org/jupyterlab-desktop-app-now-available-b8b661b17e9a)? Jupyter Notebook running on an Amazon EC2? If you just have it installed locally with the basic Jupyter Notebook, you open the Jupyter Dashboard and see which ones have active kernels indicated. Other tips: [here](https://docs.posit.co/ide/server-pro/user/2023.03.1/jupyter-lab/guide/jupyter-kernel-management.html#manage-running-kernels), ...

Comment: <continued> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70263390/8508004), [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-get-kernel-state-from-running-local-jupyter-notebook/15028/2?u=fomightez), [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/5013#issuecomment-547445419), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74026112/8508004).

Comment: @Wayne I just added more details. Thank you!